# Estimate velocity on a spring by iterative approach

Tags: python, math, physics, numerical-methods, differential-equations

The problem:

Consider a system with a mass and a spring as shown in the picture [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5ROZ.png). The stiffness of the spring and the mass of the object are known. Therefore, if the spring is stretched the force the spring exerts can be calculated from [Hooke`s law](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivRBu.png)  and the instantaneous acceleration can be estimated from Newton´s laws of motion. Integrating the acceleration twice yields the distance the spring would move and subtracting that from the initial length results in a new position to calculate the acceleration and start the loop again. Therefore as the acceleration decreases linearly the speed levels off at a certain value [(top right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwa3E.png) Everything after that point, spring compressing & decelerating is neglected for  this case.

My question is how would to go about coding that up in python. So far I have written some pseudocode.

```
instantaneous_acceleration = lambda x: 5*x/10    # a = kx/m
delta_time = 0.01     #10 milliseconds
a[0] = instantaneous_acceleration(12)     #initial acceleration when stretched to 12 m
v[0] = 0        #initial velocity 0 m/s
s[0] = 12       #initial length 12 m
i = 1
while a[i] > 12:
    v[i] = a[i-1]*delta_time + v[i-1]      #calculate the next velocity
    s[i] = v[i]*delta_time + s[i-1]        #calculate the next position
    a[i] = instantaneous_acceleration (s[i])          #use the position to derive the new accleration
    i = i + 1
```

Any help or tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sign error in the force, for a spring or any other oscillation it should always be opposite to the excitation direction. Correcting this gives instantly an oscillation. However, your loop condition will now never be satisfied, so you have to also adapt that.

You can immediately increase the order of your method by elevating it from the current symplectic Euler method to Leapfrog-Verlet. You only have to change the interpretation of `v[i]` to be the velocity at `t[i]-dt/2`. Then the first update uses the acceleration in the middle at `t[i-1]` to compute the velocity at `t[i-1]+dt/2=t[i]-dt/2` from the velocity at `t[i-1]-dt/2` using a midpoint formula. Then in the next line the position update is a similar midpoint formula using the velocity at the middle time between the position times. All you have to change in the code to get this advantage is to set the initial velocity to the one at time `t[0]-dt/2` using the Taylor expansion at `t[0]`.

```py
instantaneous_acceleration = lambda x: -5*x/10    # a = kx/m
delta_time = 0.01     #10 milliseconds
s0, v0 = 12, 0 #initial length 12 m, initial velocity 0 m/s
N=1000
s = np.zeros(N+1); v = s.copy(); a = s.copy()
a[0] = instantaneous_acceleration(s0)     #initial acceleration when stretched to 12 m
v[0] = v0-a[0]*delta_time/2        
s[0] = s0       
for i in range(N):
    v[i+1] = a[i]*delta_time + v[i]               #calculate the next velocity
    s[i+1] = v[i+1]*delta_time + s[i]             #calculate the next position
    a[i+1] = instantaneous_acceleration (s[i+1])  #use the position to derive the new acceleration
#produce plots of all these functions
t=np.arange(0,N+1)*delta_time;
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(5,3*1.5))
for g, y in zip(ax,(s,v,a)):
    g.plot(t,y); g.grid();
plt.tight_layout(); plt.show();
```

[image]

This is obviously and correctly an oscillation. The exact solution is `12*cos(sqrt(0.5)*t)`, using it and its derivatives to compute the errors in the numerical solution (remember the leap-frogging of the velocities) gives via

```
w=0.5**0.5; dt=delta_time;
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(5,3*1.5))
for g, y in zip(ax,(s-12*np.cos(w*t),v+12*w*np.sin(w*(t-dt/2)),a+12*w**2*np.cos(w*t))): 
    g.plot(t,y); g.grid();
plt.tight_layout(); plt.show();
```

the plot below, showing errors in the expected size `delta_time**2`.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to integrate up front - which is a good idea and absolutely the way to go when you can - then you can just write down the equations as functions of t for everything:

```
x'' = -kx/m
x'' + (k/m)x = 0
r^2 + k/m = 0
r^2 = -(k/m)
r = i*sqrt(k/m)
x(t) = A*e^(i*sqrt(k/m)t)
     = A*cos(sqrt(k/m)t + B) + i*A*sin(sqrt(k/m)t + B)
     = A*cos(sqrt(k/m)t + B)
```

From initial conditions we know that

```
x(0) = 12 = A*cos(B)
v(0) = 0 = -sqrt(k/m)*A*sin(B)
```

The second of these equation is true only if we choose A = 0 or B = 0 or B = Pi.

- if A = 0, then the first equation has no solution.
- if B = 0, the first equation has solution A = 12.
- if B = Pi, the first equation has solution A = -12.

We probably prefer B = 0 and A = 12. This gives

```
x(t) =  12*cos(sqrt(k/m)t)
v(t) = -12*sqrt(k/m)*sin(sqrt(k/m)t)
a(t) = -12*(k/m)cos(sqrt(k/m)t)
```

Thus, at any incremental time t[n+1] = t[n] + dt, we can simply calculate the precise position, velocity and acceleration for t[n] without any drift or inaccuracy ever accumulating.

All that said, if you are interested in how to numerically find x(t) and v(t) and a(t) given an arbitrary ordinary differential equation, the answer is much harder. There are lots of good ways of doing what can be called numerical integration. Euler's method is the easiest:

```
// initial conditions

        t[0] = 0
        x[0] = …
       x'[0] = …
         …
  x^(n-1)[0] = …
    x^(n)[0] = 0


// iterative step

  x^(n)[k+1] = f(x^(n-1)[k], …, x'[k], x[k], t[k])
x^(n-1)[k+1] = x^(n-1)[k] + dt * x^(n)[k]
             …
     x'[k+1] = x'[k] + dt * x''[k]
      x[k+1] = x[k] + dt * x'[k]
      t[k+1] = t[k] + dt
```

The smaller a value of dt you choose, the longer it takes to run for a fixed duration of time, but the more accurate the results you get. This is basically doing a Riemann sum of the function and all its derivatives up to the highest one involved in the ODE.

A more accurate version of this, Simpson's rule, does the same thing but takes the average value over the last time quantum (rather than either endpoint's value; the example above uses the beginning of the interval). The average value over the interval is guaranteed to be closer to the true value over the interval than either endpoint (unless the function was constant over that interval, in which case Simpson is at least as good).

Probably the best standard numerical integration methods for ODEs (assuming you don't need something like leapfrog methods for greater stability) are the Runge Kutta methods. An adaptive timestep Runge Kutta method of sufficient order should usually do the trick and give you accurate answers. Unfortunately, the mathematics to explain the Runge Kutta methods is probably too advanced and time consuming to cover here, but you can find information on these and other advanced techniques online or in e.g. Numerical Recipes, a series of books on numerical methods which contains lots of very useful code samples.

Even the Runge Kutta methods work basically by refining the guess at the function's value over the time quantum, though. They just do it in more sophisticated ways which provably reduce the error at each step.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation and extra pointers for further reading.